# Rails Active Record: Query by association value multiple iterations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails app where I am trying to retrieve Shoes if they have certain colors.
Currently my code is:

```
@shoes = Shoe.all
shoe_colors = params[:shoe][:colors].split('/')

shoe_colors.each do |color|
    @shoes = @shoes.joins(:colors).where('colors.name = ?', color)
end
```

I am sending all the colors in a string and then splitting it. It works great if there is only one color that I am trying to match, however if I am sending multiple colors it returns no results. I believe that I am somehow excluding all other colors on the first iteration, but I am pretty confused as to why or how I could not. I appreciate all help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that you don't have any problem with colors params, that mean `shoe_colors = params[:shoe][:colors].split('/')` ok, so your query should be

```rb
shoe_colors = params[:shoe][:colors].split('/')
@shoes = Shoe.joins(:colors)
.where('colors.name IN (?)', shoe_colors)
.group(:id).having(Arel.star.count.eq(shoe_colors.size))
```

Comment: My colors params are fine. I tried this, but the issue with the approach is that it returns a Shoe if it has any of the shoe_colors. My intention is to only return shoes if they have all of the colors in shoe_colors (if they have more colors that is fine).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of looping through the `shoe_colors` list for getting all the shoes with matching colors. Here is how you can get all the matching data:

```
shoe_colors = params[:shoe][:colors].split('/')
@shoes = Shoe.all.joins(:colors).where(colors: { name: shoe_colors })
```

Comment: My colors params are fine. I tried this, but the issue with the approach is that it returns a Shoe if it has any of the shoe_colors. My intention is to only return shoes if they have all of the colors in shoe_colors (if they have more colors that is fine).